# JOIN table in SQL PHP not working perfectly

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am trying to select the multiple tables without join and any relationship. everything is working perfectly but I got an issue that the resulting output is repeating duplicate.

I am trying to represent by diagrams.

```
`table_in`

|------|------------------|--------------|-------|
|  ID  | component_in_key |  insert_date |  type |
|------|------------------|--------------|-------|
|  1   | 123456789        |  2021-02-01  |  I    |
--------------------------------------------------

`table_request`

|------|-------------------|--------------|-------|
|  ID  | component_req_key |  insert_date |  type |
|------|-------------------|--------------|-------|
|  1   | 123456789         |  2021-02-02  |   R   |
|  2   | 123456789         |  2021-02-03  |   R   |
|  3   | 123456789         |  2021-02-04  |   R   |
---------------------------------------------------

`table_approve`

|------|-------------------|--------------|-------|
|  ID  | component_apv_key |  insert_date |  type |
|------|-------------------|--------------|-------|
|  1   | 123456789         |  2021-02-05  |   A   |
|  2   | 123456789         |  2021-02-07  |   A   |
|  3   | 123456789         |  2021-02-08  |   A   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

**trying SQL is -** `SELECT * FROM table_in, table_request, table_approve WHERE table_in.component_in_key = 123456789 AS component AND table_request.component_req_key = 123456789 AND table_approve.component_apv_key= 123456789 ORDER BY table_in.insert_date AND table_request.insert_date AND table_approve.insert_date`

**OUTPUT** `table_in.component_in_key` is repeating 3 times.

**LOOKING OUTPUT**

```
|------+---------------+--------------+-------+
|  ID  | component |  insert_date |  type |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1   | 123456789     |  2021-02-01  |  I    |
|  2   | 123456789     |  2021-02-02  |  R    |
|  3   | 123456789     |  2021-02-03  |  R    |
|  4   | 123456789     |  2021-02-04  |  R    |
|  5   | 123456789     |  2021-02-05  |  A    |
|  6   | 123456789     |  2021-02-07  |  A    |
|  7   | 123456789     |  2021-02-08  |  A    |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

Please help me how I make it like this is PHP SQL.
I am trying this for the last 3 days but not working and no threads of StackOverflow working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a `UNION` query:

```sql
SELECT ID, component_key, insert_date, type
FROM (
  SELECT ID, component_in_key AS component_key, insert_date, type
  FROM table_in
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, component_req_key, insert_date, type
  FROM table_request
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, component_apv_key, insert_date, type
  FROM table_approve
) u
WHERE component_key = 123456789
ORDER BY insert_date
```

Output:

```
ID  component_key   insert_date     type
1   123456789       2021-02-01      I
1   123456789       2021-02-02      R
2   123456789       2021-02-03      R
3   123456789       2021-02-04      R
1   123456789       2021-02-05      A
2   123456789       2021-02-07      A
3   123456789       2021-02-08      A
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW8hB4g1t6wJLnx1uMJGJ2/2)

Comment: thank you very much, you always help me in my POSTs but I am sorry to say that in my `3` tables the `component_key` is a different column name but data is same. Please update the answer sir .. I am updated my question.

Comment: May I have your Twitter account/ Facebook account/ Gmail / Whatsapp any medium so I can connect with you. I am considering you as my teacher

Comment: @SatyamSingh sorry, but I don't have the time to commit. I like SO because I can answer questions whenever I have a spare moment but right now there aren't a lot of them...

Comment: Please help last @nick your code I cant able to LEFT JOIN `all_components` table live code `https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW8hB4g1t6wJLnx1uMJGJ2/3`

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW8hB4g1t6wJLnx1uMJGJ2/4

Comment: my doubt has clear and learns really wonderful exercise in this code I want use `case` function iin `table_request` if `type = R` echo `Request` END How we do.. Please last undate sir

Comment: Just use `CASE WHEN type = 'R' THEN 'Request' ELSE 'some other value' END AS type`

Comment: btw now you have enough rep you can upvote useful answers...

Comment: hey @Nick Please help me `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686805/left-join-sum-of-column-is-duplicate-and-error-result`